# Cyrillic encoding output in R

Tags: r, encoding, output

Encoding is always a pain for me, and again it's impossible to write file with russian text. 
What should I do for this?

```
 >test = c("привет","пока")
 >test
 [1] "\320\277\321\200\320\270\320\262\320\265\321\202" "\320\277\320\276\320\272\320\260"

 >Encoding(test)
 [1] "unknown" "unknown"

 > f = file("test.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")

 > write(t,f)
 Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
 argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'

 > Encoding(test) = "UTF-8"
 > test
 [1] "<U+043F><U+0440><U+0438><U+0432><U+0435><U+0442>" "<U+043F><U+043E><U+043A><U+0430>"  

 > write(t,f)
 Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
 argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

I use R-studio 0.97.312, Mac OS 10.7.5,

Comment: What happens if you do `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Ru_Ru")` and try it?

Comment: +1 because I feel your pain with localized characters.

Comment: I just copied and pasted it on my laptop and it seems to work fine... Is this limited by the locale of your OS?

Comment: Please provide us the output of `Sys.getlocale()`

Comment: Works fine for me with the following `Sys.getlocale()` output: `"LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252;LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252;LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252"` The output of `Encoding` is `UTF-8` as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know your pain about encoding troubles:( 
Hope this will help you:

```
    > Sys.setlocale(,"ru_RU")
    [1] "ru_RU/ru_RU/ru_RU/C/ru_RU/C"
    > test = c("привет","пока")
    > write(test, file="test.txt")
```

You can even use cyrillic variables after that `Sys.setlocale(,"ru_RU")`:

```
   > привет <- rnorm(100)
   > min(привет)
   [1] -2.54578
```

Так что удачи! :)

Comment: can u please provide more clarification

Answer (score 2):

If you just visit the help page of Encoding() you find the native function enc2native(x), this'll do the trick as in

```
test = enc2utf8(c("привет","пока"))
```