# Manipulating files with non-English names in R

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization, cyrillic

When using the R functions to manipulate files in Windows,  e.g. `dir()`, those with non-English characters, like Cyrillic, are presented as a sequence of "?".

Similarly, when using `file.rename()`, if the new name contains non-English characters, the file is renamed with unreadable characters, apparently mapping to a different encoding.

There are a number of functions dealing with encoding for the file contents, but how can we deal with file names?

To reproduce the problem:
Outside R create the file "привет.txt" in the working dir; then in R:

```
dir() 
# [1] "??????.txt"      
# ...
```

Note that setting:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale="Russian")
```

doesn't help.

Note: I am using  R 3.1.2 for Windows, under Windows 8.1 *in English* and in Windows consoles (`cmd.exe`) I see the Cyrillic names properly.

Answer (score 4):

try this: `iconv("привет.txt","UTF-8","CP1251")`

Convert Character Vector between Encodings:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/iconv.html

The iconv library:
http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/recode/recode_30.html

Comment: It works like this; but, if  I use `iconv(dir() ,"UTF-8","CP1251")`,  "привет.txt"  becomes   `"??????.txt"`

Answer (score 3):

One easy solution is to change location if you only want to run the script once or twice and know the target language.

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale="Russian") 
x1<-read.table("C:\\привет.txt",head=TRUE)  #work just fine with R_3.1.2
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale="English") 
x2<-read.table("C:\\привет.txt",head=TRUE)  #will present error
```

In case you want to read from server, I strongly recommend that you use Python or other script language to process Unicode path. If you insist, I would say:
(c.f. [Set locale to system default UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577764/set-locale-to-system-default-utf-8))

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")
x3<-read.table("C:\\привет.txt",head=TRUE)  #will present warning or not, but successfully read a table into x3
```

However, you should still process this table's content using some package (e.g. stringi) and remember to revert location after this read operation if necessary.

==Update==

(c.f.https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-May/278206.html)
This may also be an inconsistent problem according to R-FAQ document:

> 3.6 I don't see characters with accents at the R console, for example in text.
>
> You need to specify a font in Rconsole (see Q5.2) that supports the
>   encoding in use. This used to be a problem in earlier versions of
>   Windows, but now it is hard to find a font which does not.
>
> Support for these characters within Rterm depends on the environment
>   (the terminal window and shell, including locale and codepage
>   settings) within which it is run as well as the font used by the
>   terminal window. Those are usually on legacy DOS settings and need to
>   altered.

Taking this, please tell me if you can input Russian file names in R-console using 'read'. Thanks.

Comment: Since I do not know Russian at all, I use @Matt 's sample filename. :-)

Comment: Say that "привет.txt" is in the working dir,  
`Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale="Russian"); dir()`, gives  "??????.txt" for "привет.txt".

Comment: @antonio Taking your comment, I tried Matt's method and my method again. Both work just fine. And I tried Chinese language, too. My machine setting is Win7(64 bit) with R 3.1.2(x64). What I did yesterday was to run script in eclipse with StatET. But I tried to use R-console now and it works just fine with me. Why not try another machine and check if your system has set up Unicode properly? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Russian_Russia.1252") `Try this. And see:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691555/cyrillic-encoding-output-in-r)[link]

Comment: @Henr.L: привет means "hello"

Answer (score 2):

I did not manage to correct the display on `dir()` function, but the function `Sys.glob(paths="*")` get you the same result as `dir()` except that it DOES display the name in cyrillic, no matter your locale setting.

For exemple, if your file is in the working directory, you can try :

```
Sys.glob(paths="*")
```

And it should display it properly as "привет.txt" (works for me). Documentation on `Sys.glob`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Sys.glob

Similarly, to **rename** the file, the proper method seems to be using a different function than `file.rename`. The following should rename a file named 'test.doc' to 'привет.txt' (works for me)

```
fs::file_move("test.doc", "привет.txt")
```

`fs` package allows to use functions closer to cmd functions to manipulate files. Documentation : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fs/vignettes/function-comparisons.html