# Reading accented filenames in R using list.files

Tags: json, r, gis, filenames, non-ascii-characters

I am reading county geojson files provided [here](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/tree/master/countries/USA/) into R Studio (R 3.1, Windows 8) for each of the states. I am using `list.files()` function in R.

For state PR, which has many counties with accented (Spanish) names viz. Bayamón.geo.json, Añasco.geo.json. The function `list.files()` returns shortened form of file names like An~asco.geo.json, Bayamo´n.geo.json.

And when in the next step I try to read the actual file using above filenames. I get an error that these files don't exist.

I was using system default encoding ISO-8859-1 and also tried changing it to UTF-8, but no luck.

Please help me solve this issue. How can I read files with accented filenames?

Comment: What exactly does the code you tried look like? Does the code work on non-accented file names? Are you running windows? A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: @MrFlick  I think that the OP listed his entire code.  It is `list.files()`. In order to reproduce the problem,  You need to create a file with a name containing an accent mark.  I simply created a new text file and named it ` Bayamón.txt`.  I get the poster's bad result.   BTW   `dir()` has the same problem.

Comment: @G5W what operating system and R version? What encoding did you use to get the accented character?

Comment: I am doing this under Windows,  R version 3.2.2.  I cut the name `Bayamón` from the post and pasted it as the file name.  I think that means UTF-8 encoding.  BTW,  in the Windows Explorer window,  the name shows up correctly.

Comment: Also,  OP mentioned R Studio.   I am using RGui.

Comment: I flippin' hate encodings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354375/manipulating-files-with-non-english-names-in-r Try changing the locale.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik  I had already tried `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale="Spanish")` but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @MrFlick I am using R Studio with R 3.1 on Windows 8 machine. If you download the files from the link I mentioned, try to list the files of PR folder. It will reproduce the error.

Comment: I was using system default ISO-8859-1 and also tried changing it to UTF-8, but no luck.

Comment: This problem is still unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I guess it happened because the default system language on my computer was different from the filenames I wanted to convert (e.g. system language = English, filename = written in french). Finally, the code below helped me to change filenames.

FILENAME_OLD is the full path for original files e.g. "C:/directory/file.wav"

FILENAME_NEW is the full path for new filenames e.g. "C:/directory/file_new.wav"

######### change filenames with non-english characters

```
path = "C:/directory"
setwd(path)

test_old <- Sys.glob('C:/directory/*')
test_new <- gsub("FILENAME_OLD",
                 "FILENAME_NEW", test_old)

file.rename(test_old, test_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1

Use `Sys.glob()` instead of list.files()

For your exemple, if you put USA as your working directory, you can type : `Sys.glob(paths="./PR/*")` to obtain a complete list, with accents, of the files in the "PR" folder.

If you want to check all files in all the working directory folder, you can type :

```
Sys.glob(paths=paste0(list.dirs(),"/*"))
```

In this code, `list.dirs()` is used to obtain the list of folders.
`paste0(list.dirs(),"/*")` simply appends "/*" to every folder path, so the function `Sys.glob` will recursively list files in every folders and subfolders.

Solution 2

If the **folders** have accents, it will NOT work. Then I would recommend to use the package **fs**. In this package, the function `dir_ls()` should work. You need to install the fs package (`install.packages("fs")` and load it with `library(fs)`), then the following code should work :

```
dir_ls(recurse=TRUE)
```

The `recurse=TRUE` option allows you to list files in subfolders.

Documentation for the fs package :

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fs/vignettes/function-comparisons.html

https://fs.r-lib.org/

Documentation on the `dir_ls` function :
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fs/versions/1.5.0/topics/dir_ls