# Rename file with strange symbols in R

Tags: r, file

I have a file with file name:

> 16900-19 odb. parcelacija katastar - sluĹľbeno  viĹˇe uloĹľaka, ÄŤl.
>   145.doc

How can I rename this file? If I tried several packages, but it always says that file doesn't exist:

```
# dont run
    list.files()
[1] "16900-19 odb. parcelacija katastar - sluĹľbeno  viĹˇe uloĹľaka, ÄŤl. 145.doc"

file.rename(list.files(), "test.doc") 
fs::file_move(list.files(), "test.doc")
```

Last line returns an error:

```
Error: [ENOENT] Failed to move '16900-19 odb. parcelacija katastar - sluÄąÄľbeno  viÄąË‡e uloÄąÄľaka, Ă„Ĺ¤l. 145.doc'to 'test.doc': no such file or directory
```

Information from sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Croatian_Croatia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Croatian_Croatia.1250    LC_MONETARY=Croatian_Croatia.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                     
[5] LC_TIME=Croatian_Croatia.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] zip_2.0.3         readxl_1.3.1.9000 RCurl_1.95-4.12   bitops_1.0-6      docker_0.0.9000   reshape2_1.4.3    reticulate_1.12   ids_1.0.1        
 [9] lubridate_1.7.4   pdftools_2.2      anytime_0.3.4     jsonlite_1.6      httr_1.4.1        mailR_0.4.1       taskscheduleR_1.4 RODBC_1.3-15     
[17] RMySQL_0.10.17    DBI_1.0.0         stringi_1.4.3     forcats_0.4.0     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_0.8.3       purrr_0.3.2.9000  readr_1.3.1      
[25] tidyr_1.0.0       tibble_2.1.3      ggplot2_3.2.0     tidyverse_1.2.1   rvest_0.3.4       xml2_1.2.2       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] carData_3.0-2      R.utils_2.9.0      modelr_0.1.4       assertthat_0.2.1   askpass_1.1        selectr_0.4-1      memisc_0.99.17.2  
 [8] cellranger_1.1.0   qpdf_1.1           pillar_1.4.2       backports_1.1.4    lattice_0.20-38    glue_1.3.1         uuid_0.1-2        
[15] digest_0.6.21      colorspace_1.4-1   htmltools_0.4.0    Matrix_1.2-17      R.oo_1.22.0        plyr_1.8.4         pkgconfig_2.0.3   
[22] broom_0.5.2        haven_2.1.1        scales_1.0.0       processx_3.4.1     openxlsx_4.1.0.1   rio_0.5.16         openssl_1.4.1     
[29] generics_0.0.2     car_3.0-3          withr_2.1.2        repr_1.0.1         lazyeval_0.2.2     cli_1.1.0          magrittr_1.5      
[36] crayon_1.3.4       ps_1.3.0           R.methodsS3_1.7.1  fs_1.3.1           fansi_0.4.0        nlme_3.1-140       MASS_7.3-51.4     
[43] foreign_0.8-71     tools_3.6.1        data.table_1.12.2  hms_0.5.1          lifecycle_0.1.0    RApiDatetime_0.0.4 munsell_0.5.0     
[50] packrat_0.5.0      compiler_3.6.1     rlang_0.4.0        grid_3.6.1         rstudioapi_0.10    base64enc_0.1-3    gtable_0.3.0      
[57] abind_1.4-5        curl_4.0           R6_2.4.0           utf8_1.1.4         zeallot_0.1.0      rJava_0.9-11       Rcpp_1.0.2        
[64] vctrs_0.2.0        tidyselect_0.2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

R probably doesn't recognise all weird symbols. You might be able to avoid this by assigning the list to a variable and using the index instead of the name:

```
list_names <- list.files
file.rename(list_names[1], "test.doc")
```

**Edit**

Well, this doesn't work. I tried several things, like replacing the "ˇ" character that isn't recognised by R (it depicts it with a "?") with the UTF-8 code, but the filename still wasn't recognised. I also found another unsolved question about this:

[Reading accented filenames in R using list.files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370357/reading-accented-filenames-in-r-using-list-files)

But none of this brings me closer to a working solution.

Comment: It works fine for me. 1) `files <- list.files(".")`  2) `file.rename(files[1],"test.doc"`) 3)  `testDF <- read.table("test.doc")` .  Also this command work fine`testDF <-  read.table("~/Desktop/16900-19 odb. parcelacija katastar - sluĹľbeno viĹˇe uloĹľaka, ÄŤl. 145.doc")`. Running on linux and R 3.6.1. Could it be an issue with R in windows?

Comment: I do use R in windows, so it might be possible

Comment: I checked on a windows machine and it is indeed a windows issue. Have a look at this solution : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48594095/read-in-non-ascii-file-path-on-windows`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in R that supports non-English characters better than "list.files" : `Sys.glob()`

The following codes work :

```
Sys.glob(paths="*")
[1] "16900-19 odb. parcelacija katastar - sluĹľbeno  viĹˇe uloĹľaka, ÄŤl. 145.doc"

file.rename(Sys.glob(paths="*"), "test.doc") 
[1] TRUE
```

Or

```
Sys.glob(paths="*")
[1] "16900-19 odb. parcelacija katastar - sluĹľbeno  viĹˇe uloĹľaka, ÄŤl. 145.doc"

fs::file_move(Sys.glob(paths="*"), "test.doc")
```

You can check `Sys.glob` documentation here : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Sys.glob

If this solves your issue please check it as "solved" !