# dir() and list.file() with non-english names in R

Tags: r, windows, encoding

One more problem with encoding on Windows. When I'm using the following functions

```
dir()
list.files()
```

in R, they return some symbols as "?". For example, it reads `"käsitelty"` as `"k?sitelty"`. I've tried with

```
Sys.setlocale(, "finnish")
```

but it didn't help.

I've tried them on different machines and realized that on some of them, the above mentioned functions works just fine for non-English characters. Perhaps, something wrong with the system. The R language version is the same.

There is a topic,
[Manipulating files with non-English names in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354375/manipulating-files-with-non-english-names-in-r), where some recommendations are given, but I need some clarification, how can I check if the Unicode is properly installed? Or what is the possible solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use `Sys.glob(paths="*")` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69153762/8436923