# How to open .xlsx files such that filenames saved as utf8 (persian/ arabic characters ) in R using Openxlsx package?

Tags: r, utf-8, filenames, openxlsx

I have 3000 files saved as Persian characters for example, "فایل ۱.xlsx". When I try to open these files (using Openxlsx package), I got following error:

```
 library(openxlsx)
 > file_temp<-file.choose()
 > parameters_old<-read.xlsx(file_temp,sheet = "parameters")
 Error in unzip(xlsxFile, exdir = xmlDir) : 
 unable to translate 'D:\allfiles\<U+0627><U+0631><U+062F><U+0628><U+06CC><U+0644>.xlsx' to                     
 native encoding
```

Is there any method to open the files?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24354375/680068

Comment: If you don't want to change your locale, you might be able to solve this issue with `gzcon` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400973/8436923  Another possibility is, `readBin` should be able to read a file whose name is encoded in UTF-8; then save it to a (temporary) file with an ASCII name that can be read by openxlsx.