# How to make RStudio treat cyriclic (Russian) symbols properly

Tags: r, ide, locale, rstudio

The problem is simple and annoying. I cannot print russian text neither in console nor in file.

Input: 
`print("hello world")
print("привет мир")`

Output:

```
> print("hello world")
[1] "hello world"
> print("привет мир")
[1] "ïðèâåò ìèð"
```

I would not use russian at all, but sometimes I get errors in russian, and since they are not readable, I have no way to treat those errors:

```
> load(swirl)
Error in load(swirl) : íåïðàâèëüíûé àðãóìåíò 'file'
```

Comment: [This could be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691555/cyrillic-encoding-output-in-r)

Comment: "but sometimes I get errors in russian" --> Add `Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="EN")` to the Rprofile.site file of your R installation. Localization of error messages is mostly a nuisance.