# Encoding of cyrillic symbols in R

Tags: r, encoding, cyrillic

all.

I have to use cyrillic symbols, but I have trouble with it. When I print it in console everything is fine. But in `view` function and write to `.csv` characters are unreadable.  [Look at picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10HDv.png)

Comment: you can look at [Cyrillic encoding output in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691555/cyrillic-encoding-output-in-r). Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. It realy works.